# Plotting and positioning in LaTeX of multiple times series from multiple files

Tags: r, latex, ggplot2, gnuplot

I have 50 files containing 3 time series in each of them with identical tab separated format. To be specific each file contains 250 observations and looks like below:

```
1 8.83229 0.02544 0.02544
2 2.95561 0.02544 0.02544
3 1.27395 0.02544 0.02544
4 2.01115 0.02544 0.02544
5 2.38058 0.02383 0.02383
6 1.10755 0.02383 0.02383
7 1.16735 0.02013 0.02013
8 1.57755 0.02013 0.02013
9 1.81942 0.02013 0.02013
10 1.45921 0.01611 0.01611
...
246 0.04564 0.02383 0.01611
247 0.04357 0.02383 0.01611
248 0.03651 0.02383 0.01611
249 0.03334 0.02383 0.01611
250 0.03438 0.02383 0.01611
```

The first column is obviously index and the other three columns are time series. I've written a gnuplot script to be called from another shell script in order to plot all these 50 files. But i'd like to organise these plots in such a manner that, 3x4 or 4x5 of them, to be in one A4, in a publication written with LaTeX. Is there a LaTeX package or gnuplot trick for this? Maybe it is easier to do this with R? Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this,

```
library(reshape2)
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)

setwd("/Users/baptiste/data/")

lf <- list.files(pattern=".txt")

read_file <- function(f, ...){

  result <- read.table(f, ...)
  names(result) <- c("id", "ts1", "ts2", "ts3")
  result

}

## read all files in a list
all <- llply(lf, read_file, .progress="text")
names(all) <- paste0("file", seq_along(all))

m <- melt(all, id = "id") # to long format
str(m)

## facetted plot
ggplot(m) + facet_wrap( ~ L1, ncol = 4 ) +
  geom_path(aes(id, value, colour = variable))

ggsave("facetted_plot.pdf", width = 10, height = 10)

## alternative: multiple plots
library(gridExtra)
plots <- dlply(m, "L1", function(d) {
  ggplot(d) + geom_path(aes(id, value, colour = variable))
})
ml <- do.call(marrangeGrob, c(plots, list(nrow=3, ncol=4)))

ml
## multipage pdf with 3x4 on each page
ggsave("multipage.pdf", ml)
```

(untested)

Comment: This really helped, thank you! One more and last question: I've decided to follow "facetted plot strategy", as it seems more appealing to me. Question is; ts1 has a much more broader range than ts2 and ts3. Before i came here, i had written a gnuplot script which had a two y axes one for ts1 and; one for ts2 and ts3. As i've read ggplot2 documentation multiple y axes are not seen as favorable as gnuplot. So; i've decided to make two facetted plot one for ts1 and one for the remaining. Can you help me to do that?

Comment: at some point (hint: from the start) it becomes easier to discuss with some (mockup) data, so that we can propose code that actually runs. Anyway, maybe you can add a column to `m` above, like `m$ts <- ifelse(m$variable == "ts1", "ts1", "ts23")` and facet with both `L1` and `ts`, `facet_grid(ts ~ L1, scales = "free")`.

Answer (score 3):

Making these kinds of composite plots is really easy to do using either `lattice` or `ggplot2`. I favor `ggplot2`, where these kinds of composite plots are constructed using facetting. A visual teaser of how such a plot would look like ([from here](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/facet_grid.html)):

```
p <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, ..density..)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.2) + facet_grid(clarity ~ cut)
```

[image]

This is a histogram, but you can quite easily draw timeseries like this. Or take a look at figure 3.6 from a [report I wrote](http://www.numbertheory.nl/files/report_evap.pdf). Note that there is no need to create separate plots, ggplot2 takes care of it all, it is one big plot with a lot of subplots. Take a look at the [ggplot2 docs here](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/) to get more detail.